# Cross Compile zlib and openssl from docker linux container to armv7 error libz.so: file not recognized: file format not recognized

Tags: openssl, cross-compiling, zlib, openssh

I have been trying for weeks to cross compile zlib, openssl, and openssh. Last attempt resulted in an error in cross compiling openssl:

/usr/local/zlib/lib/libz.so: file not recognized: file format not recognized

Here is the last attempt I made:

```
# installing zlib
wget $WGET_URL/zlib-1.2.13.tar.gz -O /tmp/zlib.tar.gz -q && \
mkdir /tmp/zlib && \
tar -xvf /tmp/zlib.tar.gz -C /tmp/zlib && \
rm -rf zlib.tar.gz && \
cd /tmp/zlib/*/ && \
CHOST=arm && \
CC=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc && \
AR=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar && \
RANLIB=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib && \
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/zlib && \
make clean && \
make install && \   
cd /tmp && \
rm -r -f /tmp/zlib && \
# installing openssl
wget $WGET_URL/openssl-3.0.7.tar.gz -O /tmp/openssl.tar.gz -q && \
mkdir /tmp/openssl && \
tar -xvf /tmp/openssl.tar.gz -C /tmp/openssl && \
rm -rf openssl.tar.gz && \
cd /tmp/openssl/*/ && \
./config linux-generic32 -DL_ENDIAN --prefix=/usr/local/openssl 
--with-zlib-include=/usr/local/zlib/include 
    --with-zlib-    lib=/usr/local/zlib/lib shared zlib && \
    make CC=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc 
LD=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc         
MAKEDEPPROG=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc PROCESSOR=ARM && \
    make install CC=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc 
    LD=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc     
MAKEDEPPROG=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc PROCESSOR=ARM
```

Here is the output of "file /usr/local/zlib/lib/libz.so"

/usr/local/zlib/lib/libz.so: symbolic link to libz.so.1.2.13

Finally did get zlib and openssl to compile although I'm sure there is more work to be done to get the application to do what I want..

```
# installing zlib
wget $WGET_URL/zlib-1.2.13.tar.gz -O /tmp/zlib.tar.gz - 
q && \
mkdir /tmp/zlib && \
tar -xvf /tmp/zlib.tar.gz -C /tmp/zlib && \
rm -rf zlib.tar.gz && \
cd /tmp/zlib/*/ && \
CROSS_PREFIX=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux- 
gnueabihf- && \
./configure --prefix=/usr/arm/zlib && \
make clean && \
    make  && \
make install && \  
cd /tmp && \
rm -r -f /tmp/zlib && \

# installing openssl
wget $WGET_URL/openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz -O /tmp/openssl.tar.gz -q && \
mkdir /tmp/openssl && \
tar -xvf /tmp/openssl.tar.gz -C /tmp/openssl && \
rm -rf openssl.tar.gz && \
cd /tmp/openssl/*/ && \
./Configure linux-generic32 shared  -DL_ENDIAN --prefix=/usr/arm/openssl 
--openssldir=/usr/arm/openssl && \
make CC=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc 
RANLIB=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ranlib 
LD=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ld 
MAKEDEPPROG=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-gcc PROCESSOR=ARM && \
make install_sw CC=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc 
RANLIB=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ranlib  
LD=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ld 
MAKEDEPPROG=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-gcc PROCESSOR=ARM && \ 
cd /tmp && \
rm -r -f /tmp/openssl



enter code here
```

Comment: Check with ```file(1)``` what fileformat your libz.so file is. Zlib configure requires an --archs argument, you did not provide one.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Is there a list of --archs types?  I can't find one.  My processor is armv7.

Comment: Please run "file /usr/local/zlib/lib/libz.so" and [edit] your question to include the output.

Comment: I'll rebuild it without openssl and openssh and run it on the arm and give you the results.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I added the edit and here is the out put - /usr/local/zlib/lib/libz.so: symbolic link to libz.so.1.2.13

Comment: I added --archs=armv7 to configure but then it says " Compiler error reporting is too harsh for ./configure (perhaps remove -Werror)."